# Performance of a function that changes functions

Tags: haskell

Lets suppose we have a function

```
type Func = Bool -> SophisticatedData
fun1 :: Func
```

And we'd like to change this function some input:

```
change :: SophisticatedData -> Func -> Func
change data func = \input -> if input == False then data else func input
```

Am I right that after several calls of `change` (`endFunc = change data1 $ change data2 $ startFunc`) resulting function would call all intermediate ones each time? Am I right that GC wouldn't able to delete unused data? What is the haskell way to cope with this task?

Thanks.

Comment: With GHC, you won't even compute the data until it's needed (lazily), or if you've forced evaluation the GC should be able to clean it up after there are no more references to it.

Comment: A sidenote: `data` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Well let's start by cleaning up change to be a bit more legible

```
change sd f input = if input then func input else sd
```

So when we compose these

```
change d1 $ change d2 $ change d3
```

GHC starts by storing a thunk for each of them. Remember that `$` is a function to so the whole `change d*` thing is going to be a thunk at first. Thunks are relatively cheap and if you're not creating 10k or so of them at once you'll be just fine :) so no worries there.

Now the question is, what happens when you start evaluating, the answer is, it'll still not evaluate the complex data, so it's still quite memory efficient, and it only needs to force `input` to determine which branch it's taking. Because of this, you should never actually fully evaluate `SophisticatedData` until after choose has run and returned a one to you, then it will be evaluated as need if you use it.

Further more, at each step, GHC can garbage collect the unneeded thunks since they can't be referenced anymore.

In conclusion, you should be just fine. Trust in the laziness

Comment: So, if I have about O(n) of `$`s, each call of such function is O(n)?

Comment: @ElectricHedgehog Space or speed?

Comment: speed. I suppose space is O(n) total for all calls.

Comment: @ElectricHedgehog Yes, It's just branching.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: if `foo` is a chain of O(n) calls to `change`, there will be O(n) overhead on every call to `foo`. The way to deal with this is to memoize `foo`:

```
memoize :: Func -> Func
memoize f = \x -> if x then fTrue else fFalse where
    fTrue  = f True
    fFalse = f False
```

Comment: You are right, but you should add `$!` operator into `fTrue = f $! True`. In the other case evaluations would be lazy and, again, function `memoize` would be calculated each time.

Comment: @ElectricHedgehog Your claim that `fTrue` would be lazy is correct, but your claim that the memoized function would incur the O(n) cost each time is incorrect. Test it yourself!